# How to parse Json to a JQuery function and get the values inside the function

Tags: jquery, json

i am trying to create a plugin "bg-rotator" that takes parameters in JSON format:

```
$('.selector').bg_rotator({
    'duration':500,
    'delay':5000
});
```

Then in my Jquery function I am trying to get the JSON object and split the values:

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.bg_rotator = function(jsonObj) {
      var cn = $(this).attr('class'); //get the class name
      var obj = JSON.parse(jsonObj); //get the Json object
      var duration = obj.duration;
      var delay = obj.delay;
   }; 
})( jQuery );
```

This is giving me errors and I can't find the way to parse and get the JSON values.
Any ideas? Thanks

This worked:

```
(function( $ ){
     $.fn.bg_rotator = function(jsonObj) {
           var cn = $(this).attr('class'); //get the class name
           var duration = jsonObj.duration; //get the Json object
           var delay = jsonObj.delay;
     };
   })( jQuery );
```

Comment: try console.log(jsonObj) and see if you are accessing the correct properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is Javascript Object Notation. The idea is that they are essentially just regular Javascript objects, so you can use them like regular Javascript objects. You don't need to parse objects unless they have been stringified. In this case you're just passing a regular object, so you simply access the object's properties, no parsing necessary.

Comment: Great!, I was complicating my life, if anybody finds this trouble it is simply as @Natahan Bouscal says just use the object as it is parsed, look at my question for exact code.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use JSON.parse as you are already passing json object

just remove JSON.parse and try it, it will works

**var obj = jsonObj; //get the Json object**

JSON.parse is used to parse string to json object
e.g

**JSON.parse("{'duration':500,'delay':5000}")**

Answer (score 0):

Try just calling jsonObj.duration.